# Passing a CLOB into a .net dll

Tags: c#, .net, vgl

I wanted to know if it were possible to pass a CLOB (8k String) to a .net dll? 
Is there max limit on what a dll can receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by "pass to a dll".

If you mean calling a method where the parameter is a string then I think your bound by string length, which is Int32.MaxValue or 2,147,483,647 characters.